# check if two segments on the same circle overlap / intersect

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry, 2d, angle

Given two circle segments of the same circle: A=[a1, a2] and B=[b1, b2], with:

- a1, a2, b1, b2 values in degree between -inf and +inf
- a1 <= a2 ; b1 <= b2
- a2-a1<=360; b2-b1<=360

How can I find out if these two circle segments overlap?
(i.E. if they intersect or touch in at least one point)

Examples:

```
A=[  -45°,    45°]; B=[   10°,   20°] ==> overlap
A=[  -45°,    45°]; B=[   90°,  180°] ==> no overlap
A=[  -45°,    45°]; B=[  180°,  360°] ==> overlap
A=[ -405°,  -315°]; B=[  180°,  360°] ==> overlap
A=[-3600°, -3601°]; B=[ 3601°, 3602°] ==> overlap (touching counts as overlap)
A=[ 3600°,  3601°]; B=[-3601°,-3602°] ==> overlap (touching counts as overlap)
A=[    -1°,    1°]; B=[ 3602°, 3603°] ==> no overlap
```

This looks like a deceptively simple problem but I cannot wrap my head around it.
I currently have a basic idea for a solution which involves splitting each segment into two if it crosses 0°, but I am not sure if that covers all cases, and I was wondering if there is an elegant formula.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intersection between two Arcs? (arc = distance between pair of angles)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800829/intersection-between-two-arcs-arc-distance-between-pair-of-angles)

Comment: Given you don't specify radius of circle or center are we to assume that the arcs are on the same circle?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I do not think that other question is a duplicate. The answer for that question involves sorting arrays and managing a list of neighboring segments.

Comment: @Chris Yes, the segments are on the same circle; I had that in the text, but the title might have been unclear, I modified the question title to reflect this fact

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I just saw you modified the link; that other question looks indeed related, thought they only appear to have angles between 0° and 360°. The answer seems similar to my basic idea of splitting segments, I'd be interested to find out if that is indeed a working solution for my problem, and if there are any better ones?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @admaoldak  mentioned, normalize the degrees first:

```
a1_norm = a1 % 360
a2_norm = a2 % 360
b1_norm = b1 % 360
b2_norm = b2 % 360
```

Now to check if b1 is within (a1,a2),

```
def intersect(b, as, ae
    Intersect = False
    If as > ae:
        if b >= as or b <= ae:
            return True
    Else:
        if b>=as and b<=ae:
            return True
    return False
```

Final answer is:

```
intersect(b1_norm,a1_norm,a2_norm)||intersect(b2_norm,a1_norm,a2_norm)||
intersect(a1_norm,b1_norm,b2_norm)||intersect(a2_norm,b1_norm,b2_norm)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I used; altough if speed were an issue, I think that it would be sufficient to only check for `intersect(b1_norm,a1_norm,a2_norm)||intersect(a1_norm,b1_norm,b2_norm)` to cover all cases

Comment: what about A=[  -45°,    45°]; B=[  180°,  359°] ==> overlap

Comment: Note, modulos often aren't implemented correctly for negative numbers (I don't know about python but it is the case in most C lineage languages)

Answer (score 2):

For an interval [i.X , i.Y] , let's define the normalization **i_norm = normalize(i)**  so that :

```
1. 0 <= i_norm.X < 360
2. i_norm.X <=i_norm.Y
```

then we define another operation **i_slide = slide(i)** so that :

```
1. i_slide.X = i.X + 360
2. i_slide.Y = i.Y + 360
```

we can prove that,
for your input **A** and **B** , **A** *circle-overlaps* with **B** if and only if :

> **normalize(A)** *interval-overlaps* with **normalize(B)**
>
> or
>
> **normalize(A)** *interval-overlaps* with **slide( normalize(B))**

*interval-overlaps* is defined in the same way as "intersection" in adamoldak's post.

and both operations **normalize()** and **slide()** are easy to be implemented.

take your example: `A=[-45°,45°]; B=[10°,20°]`  , we have

```
normalize(A) = [315,405] 
normalize(B) = [10,20] 
slide( normalize(B) ) = [370,380]
```

and [315,405] *interval-overlaps* with [370,380]

Comment: Switch A & B and your example breaks. You need to check norm(A) vs norm(B), slide(norm(A)) vs norm(B) & norm(A) vs slide(norm(B)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with a game engine with rectangles overlapping in a looping map. I've thought about it a lot and have looked at some of you guys' answers. If you're looking for performance, this is the best you can get (until someone proves me wrong :P):

```py
#assume the angles are already normalised
def overlap(a1, a2, b1, b2):
  if a2 - a1 + b2 - b1 > 360: #must overlap
    return True
  return (b1 > a2) ^ (b2 > a1) ^ (a2 < a1) ^ (b2 < b1)
```

Elegant. Elegant and kinda ugly.

Answer (score -1):

How about normalizing each degree value to 0-360:

```
a1_norm = a1 % 360
a2_norm = a2 % 360
b1_norm = b1 % 360
b2_norm = b2 % 360
```

Then you just check for intersection:

```
(a1_norm <= b2_norm) and (a2_norm<= b1_norm)
```

Comment: A=[-45°,45°]; B=[10°,20°] ==> A=[315°,45°]; B=[10°,20°], then a1_norm is > b2_norm despite overlap