# Check if partial arc intersects circle

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to check if an arc and a circle intersect each other.

I can tell if they intersect if i assume that the arc is also a circle, with the code below. but i can not seem to find a solution to do this with an arc and a circle (or two arcs).
For the circle i have the following data: center, radius. for the arc i have the following data: center, start point of arc, end point of arc, angle of arc center to two points, start angle, end angle.

```
//distance between two circles
var d = this.center.distanceTo(cursor.center);

// Check Intersections
if (d > (this.radius + cursor.radius)) {
    //Circles do not intersect
    return false;
} else if (d < this.radius - cursor.radius) {
    // No Solution. one circle is contained in the other
    return false;
} else {
    //circles intersect
    return true;
}
```

What i would like is a result if the arc and circle intersect. And if possible, but not needed yet, what the coordinates are of the intersections.

i have looked at [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800829/intersection-between-two-arcs-arc-distance-between-pair-of-angles) but can't make heads or tails from it to translate it to code formula.

Comment: You are having more of a https://math.stackexchange.com/ problem than a SO problem. I don't know your education level but you have a bit more specific problem than a general one  - Two functions intersecting. You are basically searching all X where following is true: f(x) = g(x) where f is a circle and g is an arc

Comment: If exact math answer is not what you are after, but a simple solution will do if might be fun to represent both functions in a graph plot, one with yelow and other one with blue, and set both so semi transparent then search the graph for green, if any there is intersection.  Its fun since its visual, but in no means this is the most precise way.

Answer (score 0):

Your arc circle's midpoint has an angle from its midpoint that points towards the other circle.  Find the closest angle to that angle that lies within the arc, and project to the appropriate point on the arc.
If that point lies within the circle, then you know your arc intersects the circle.

Comment: This is from my intuition, you might want to test this.